# How to specify root level array, of minimal size and each object matching pattern

Tags: java, pact

I have problems creating a DSL in pact, which will accept array of minimal size where each element matches given object pattern. I have no problems when I have an array inside a JSON object, then I can simply call:

```
DslPart body = new PactDslJsonBody()
        .minArrayLike("users")
            .id()
            .stringType("name")
        .closeObject()
        .closeArray();
```

But how can I do it in case Array is the root object? I tried following:

```
new PactDslJsonArray()
        .minArrayLike("users")
            .id()
            .stringType("name")
        .closeObject()
        .closeArray();
```

But the pattern does not comply with request (it looks like it expects an array inside an array, since it throws deserialization exception saying, that '[' character was unexpected).

Answer (score 1):

I must have been blind while reading documentation, which clearly states that one can do it using static interface of PactDslJsonArray:

```
PactDslJsonArray.minArrayLike()
    .date("clearedDate", "mm/dd/yyyy", date)
    .stringType("status", "STATUS")
    .decimalType("amount", 100.0)
.closeObject()
```